# Allow only one request per ip and url

Tags: php, apache-2.2, http

Using a htaccess file or sending special headers from php, is there any way to allow only one http request by ip **and** url? I mean, an user could make multiple request simultaneously, but not to the same url (file).

The issue comes with the download accelerators. I need to allow multiple dowloads at the same time and **also** pause and/or resume them (bc of failures in the client's connection, mainly), but disable that annoying function of having multiple partial downloads at the same time because they are making the server crash because of the amount of simultaneously requests.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I saw that, but the thing is to allow multiple requests from the same ip, but only if the uri are distinct.

Comment: ip!=user, one user could have multiple ips and 1 ip could be multiple users.

Comment: This can be accomplished by creating sessions, and/or using a database? Which method would you prefer. The efficient way, would be to utilize a database, that way when a session is destroyed, they still will not be able to access the URL.

Comment: Hi. ip!=user, thats true, I should consider it. And yes, I'm doing this programatically if I can't do it as asked, just wanted to know if there were a sipler way first. Thank you two!

Answer (score 0):

The server should *not* crash because of the amount of simultaneous requests. If you are using Apache (as per question tags) try lowering (even dramatically) MaxClients and MinSpareServers or MinSpareThreads. Or also, try out nginx.

Comment: Hi, thank you, it's a shared server, sadly I can't decide that.